# How to search name, (OPTIONAL) second name, surname on SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am not usually an SQL person but need to find matching name/surnames from a list of people on MSSql. I am trying to find similar names from TABLENAME to match the list of people that I have. The line looks like this:

```
Select * 
from TABLENAME(nolock)
Where SomeRule='04' and RTRIM(Name) +' ' + RTRIM(SecondName) +' '+RTRIM(Surname) in (THE LIST OF PEOPLE HERE)
```

But this method only gives me the match of people with second names. If someone does not have a second name but their name+surname match, it does not show up. I want to see people who have 100% match of name-second name-surname OR name-surname (if they don't have second name).
Thank you guys in advance

Comment: Any chance THE LIST OF PEOPLE HERE could be a table(Name,SecondName,Surname)?

Comment: It was just given to me in an Excel list, therefore I copy and pasted in the form above. But I can try and convert it into a table for this task if needed

Comment: For someone who is "not usually an SQL person" you seem pretty confident in using `nolock`, I hope you don't mind incorrect results. And is there any reason you are still using an out of date version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

Provided list of people is a table

```
Select distinct t.* 
from TABLENAME t
join [THE LIST OF PEOPLE HERE] lp on SomeRule='04' 
     and RTRIM(t.Name) = lp.Name 
     and RTRIM(t.Surname) = lp.Surname 
     and (t.SecondName is null and pl.SecondName is null or RTRIM(t.SecondName) = lp.SecondName)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at some rows:

| Name | SecondName | Surname | Remark | Your concatenation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 'John' | 'Thomas' | 'Smith' | Person with middle name | 'John Thomas Smith' |
| 'John' | '' | 'Smith' | Person that has no middle name | 'John Smith' |
| 'John' | null | 'Smith' | Person with an unknown middle name | null |

The person without a middle name cannot be found because of two blanks separating first and last name in your created string. The person of whom we don't know the middle name cannot be found because the concatenated string is null.

You can use `CASE WHEN` to check this and react accordingly:

```
select * 
from tablename
where somerule = '04'
and
  rtrim(name) + ' ' + 
  case when rtrim(secondname) is null then ''
       when rtrim(secondname) = '' then ''
       else rtrim(secondname) + ' '
  end +
  rtrim(surname) in (the list of people here)
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know there was a case when scenario for SQL. I really appreciate it